# конвертировать массив из javascript в c#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

В проекте на c# использую скипт JS для сбора ссылочек. Сам скрипт на js:

```
const items = window.document.querySelectorAll('someThing');
const res = [];
items.forEach(function(item)
{
    const str = item.querySelector('a');
    res.push(str.href);
})
return res;
```

Используется драйвер селениума:

```
IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
```

пытался сделать что-то подобное, но оно не конвертит в лист стринг

```
List<string> title = (List<string>)js.ExecuteScript("script");
```

Как получить массив собранных ссылочек из Javascript в проекте C#?

Comment: что такое `js.ExecuteScript`?

Comment: IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
driver - драйвер селениума

Comment: Агааааа... а `IJavaScriptExecutor` откуда? :-) и что такое `driver`? :)

Comment: Ну вот :-) так уже понятнее :-) стоило сразу указать, что речь про селениум. Самый простой путь - посмотреть в отладчике, что именно возвращает `ExecuteScript` в данном конкретном случае и уже на основе этого решать как именно скастить результат в список строк.

Comment: не удается определить тип, сразу ошибка

Comment: сделай `var o = js.ExecuteScript("script");` и посмотри что лежит в `o`

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему следующим образом:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

object result = js.ExecuteScript("some script");
ReadOnlyCollection<object> list = (ReadOnlyCollection<object>)result;

foreach (object elem in list)
{
  _listLinks.Add((string)elem;
}

File.WriteAllLines("C:\\file.txt", _listLinks);
```

Мой js возвращает по сути массив, поэтому я беру ридонли коллекцию. Если бы возвращало что-то "одиночное" (цифра, строка), то, думаю, можно было бы просто object